# How to make same value of one column for those rows which have same values in another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where some of the rows in a column named `'Case_num'` have the same value. I want to fill the column named `'Work_Hrs'` with a sum of the non-zero values in that column if `'Case_num'` is the same. For example, the input data is:

[image]

I want to fill the column `'Work_Hrs'` with a sum of non zero values, i.e. 6 in this case, see below:

[image: Output is:]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:
I have created a similar sample:

```
dic={'Work':[0,1,2,4,1],'Case_Num':[1,1,1,3,3]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)

   Work Case_Num
0   0   1
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   4   3
4   1   3
```

Grouping by the column and apply `sum` on target column

```
sum_series=df.groupby('Case_Num')['Work'].sum()
Case_Num
1    3
3    5
Name: Work, dtype: int64
```

And then create function to apply on dataframe

```
def change_value(case,work):
if work==0:
    work=sum_series[case]
return work

df['Work']=df.apply(lambda x: change_value(x['Case_Num'],x['Work']),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Work Case_Num
0   3   1
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   4   3
4   1   3
```

**Update** For changing `Work` column with sum everywhere, you can use following

```
df['Work']=df['Case_Num'].apply(lambda x: sum_series[x])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Based on the expected output I think that @vaibhav pandey wants to replace all the 'work_hrs' with the some for a given 'case', not only where it equals 0.

Comment: Thanks, but the work value should be {3,3,3,5,5}. Sorry for my bad english if the question was not clear.

Comment: @vaibhavpandey that can be done in single line `df['Work']=df['Case_Num'].apply(lambda x: sum_series[x])` . Let me edit the answer and then you can accept

Comment: @N.Moudgil, Thank you very much